# Qt Как выполнить метод в главном потоке?

Tags: c++, qt, многопоточность, qt4

У меня есть приложение которое выполняет некоторую работу в отдельном потоке:

```
class Worker : public QRunnable{
public:
    void run(){
        //Какие-то действия
    }
};

class MainWindow : public QWidget{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0):
        QWidget(parent)
    {
        QThreadPool::globalInstance()->start(new Worker);
    }
};
```

Мне необходимо вызвать в методе `run` функцию из другой библиотеки, которая ничего не знает о потоках Qt и не дружит с ними ни под каким предлогом:

```
void run(){
    //...
    iHateQtThreads(arg1, arg2, arg3);  //Ошибка
    //...
}
```

Нужно каким-то способом вызвать эту функцию в главном потоке.
Какой есть красивый способ это сделать?

**PS:** Функция вызывается многократно с определенным интервалом. Если использовать синалы/слоты с подключением `Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection` или `Qt::QueuedConnection`, то интервал нарушается. Сигналы сначала накапливаются, а потом выстреливают все разом.

Comment: Какая ошибка возникает при использовании функции внутри потока?

Comment: @KoVadim, внутри функции пытается заблокироваться мьютекс, который не может понять в каком потоке он находится, так как он ничего не знает о потоках Qt. Ну да это и не важно. Лезть в реализацию функции все равно нельзя.

Comment: потоки Qt ничем не отличаются от потоков операционной системы. Поэтому, если функция пытается понять, а не под Qt ли она запущена, то это интересная функция. Что за библиотека, что она пытается сделать? думаю, что функция может работать в отдельном потоке, скорее всего она не может работать "в паралель".

Comment: @KoVadim, то что потоки не отличаются это верно, тут проблема в том что эта библиотека каким-то образом отслеживает создаваемые потоки, и она не готова к тому, что их начнет создавать кто-то другой. По правде говоря, есть специальная функция, для того чтобы указать этой библиотеке поток, созданный кем-то другим, но она почему-то не работает только под linux.

Comment: Может все таки озвучите имя библиотеки? На самом деле сейчас пытаемся пофиксить багу либо либы, либо в Вашем коде, при этом не зная что за либа.

Comment: @KoVadim, библиотека собственная, никому не известная. Нужна как прослойка для работы с системами реального времени. Конкретно эта функция отправляет сообщение по сети. Работать "в параллель" она может, и работает. Но только в том случае если потоки созданы при помощи её библиотеки

Comment: @KoVadim, баг в библиотеке определенно есть. Функция, которая привязывает чужой поток к этой библиотеке, просто не работает. Поэтому ищу способ его обойти на своем уровне. Даже не так, способ я уже придумал, а вот как его реализовать не знаю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вызов функции через очередь посредством сигнал/слотов или `QMetaObject::invokeMethod()` - это по сути декларация о намерении. Лишь когда контекст выполнения целевого потока перейдёт к перебору очереди событий, то только тогда запланированное действие (вызов функции) будет произведено.

Соответственно, если целевой поток занят какой-либо задачей и относительно редко просматривает очередь событий, то декларации на вызов функции будут накапливаться. Как только контекст выполнения целевого потока освободится и наконец перейдёт к очереди событий, то разом будут произведены все ранее запланированные вызовы функции. Чтобы этого избежать, необходимо минимизировать время нахождения контекста выполнения целевого потока во вне его очереди событий. Проще говоря, целевой поток вообще ничего не должен делать и должен находиться в постоянном ожидании, либо его работа должна быть сведена к выполнению минимума задач.

В основе вызова функции через очередь посредством сигнал/слотов или `QMetaObject::invokeMethod()` лежит создание и отправка объекта события `QMetaCallEvent`. В целевой поток объект события отправляется посредством метода `QCoreApplication::postEvent()`, у которого в свою очередь имеется аргумент приоритетности выполнения со значением по умолчанию `Qt::NormalEventPriority`. Чем выше приоритет события, тем ранее оно будет выполнено обработчиком в очереди событий. Разумеется при условии, что контекст выполнения целевого потока не отвлекается на длительное время с целью выполнения посторонних задач.

К сожалению, в Qt не предусмотрена возможность указывать приоритет выполнения событий, создаваемых посредством вызова сигналов. Также, не предусмотрено это и при вызове `QMetaObject::invokeMethod()`. Однако никто не мешает организовать свою реализацию той же техники, но на основе собственного типа событий.

Например, произвольное событие:

```
Q_GLOBAL_STATIC_WITH_ARGS(int, _g_event_type
    , (QEvent::registerEventType()))

class IHateQtThreadsEvent : public QEvent {
    public:
        static QEvent::Type eventType() {
            return static_cast<QEvent::Type>(*_g_event_type);
        }

        IHateQtThreadsEvent()
            : QEvent(IHateQtThreadsEvent::eventType()) {}
};
```

... можно отправлять из потока-источника обычным в Qt образом, но с указанием повышенного уровня приоритетности:

```
void run() {
    ...
    QCoreApplication::postEvent(receiver_obj
        , new IHateQtThreadsEvent()
        , Qt::HighEventPriority);
    ...
}
```

Указатель "receiver_obj" - это произвольный наследник `QObject`, "живущий" в целевом потоке. Для него останется лишь добавить пользовательский обработчик событий:

```
class IHateQtThreadsObject : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

    protected:
        virtual void customEvent(QEvent *event) {
            if(event->type() == IHateQtThreadsEvent::eventType()) {
                // Аргументы для вызова функции могут быть переданы
                // в объекте события.
                iHateQtThreads(arg1, arg2, arg3);
            }
        }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Класс QRunnable не является потомком QObject, значит не может отправлять или получать сигналы и не может обрабатывать события.

Следовательно надо создавать новый поток как QThread. И уже из этого потока испускать сигнал, по которому выполнится слот iHateQtThreads() главного потока.

Comment: Вполне можно сделать так `class Worker : public QRunnable, public QObject`. А вот с сигналами проблема которую я описал в **ps**