# Запустить слот в его потоке

Tags: c++, qt

Для объекта был вызван метод `QObject::moveToThread`. Следовательно, при поступлении сигналов соответствующие слоты выполняются в указанном потоке. Иногда добавление сигналов только для того, чтобы вызвать соответствующий слот, неоправданно: оно засоряет код. Я нашёл такой способ вызвать слот без сигнала:

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(obj, "slot1", Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

но здесь мне не нравится использование текстового названия метода. Хотелось бы иметь проверку существования метода во время компиляции. Как можно такое сделать?

UPD. Может быть, есть способ в `QtConcurrent::run` указать конкретный поток?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В случае с `QMetaObject::invokeMethod()` проверка существования целевого метода (слота) возможна лишь на этапе выполнения программы.

`QtConcurrent` не предоставляет публичного доступа к потокам, а потому выбрать конкретный не представляется возможным.

Ещё один вариант межпоточного взаимодействия - [использование событий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/580446/qt-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B2-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5). Наследуете собственный тип события от `QEvent`, а в объект, существующий в целевом потоке, пересылаете при помощи `QCoreApplication::postEvent()`. Конечно, данный подход потребует больше кода, однако позволит ещё на этапе компиляции отследить соответствие пересылаемых типов данных (хотя бы и через проверку класса события).